# Можно ли сделать контейнер в докере, в котором будет windows

Tags: linux, docker

Встал вопрос, о том, что нужно запустить веб версию приложения, которая всегда работала на винде, а именно на iss в Linux. То есть можно сделать виртуалку и запустить на линуксе, а можно ли сделать это в докере? По сути докер это же контейнер. И можно ли как то внутри этого контейнера настроить windows для запуска web версии приложения.

Comment: докер это не виртуалка. Поэтому нет. Но если Вы возьмете wine, то кто его знает. Но учитывая, что это iss, я бы не надеялся, дешевле на пхп переписать.

Comment: @KoVadim, не. Это винтуалка, только не на том уровне, который нужен для ОП.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows base OS images dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images)